# How to validate Firmware Version when using FileTransfer with OPC-UA (High Performance -SDK)

Tags: c++, c, opc-ua

I am trying to implement a Software Update using the Direct-Loading Option. Transfering the Firmware file to the Server works, but I don't know how to validate the files, for example if the version is lower than the current one the update should abort.

I tried to find the meta data in the file_handle but with no success

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.